# @Transactional in Service

Tags: spring-boot, service, transactional

**I have created a voting application and I have method that changes the number of votes. It implements an interface with @Transactional annotation.**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public interface VotingService {

    Vote getByRestaurantId(int restaurantId);

    Vote get(int id);

    List<Vote> getWithRestaurantsByDate(LocalDateTime date);

    List<Vote> getWithRestaurantsToday(HttpServletResponse response, int id);

    @Transactional
    Vote voteFor(int restaurantId, int userId);
}
```

I use SpringBoot. **Will it work correctly while simultaneously voting several users. And how can you test such an action?**

The sequential voting is working properly.

Code for changes the number of voices like this:

```
    @Service
    public class VotingServiceImpl implements VotingService {
    ...

    @Override
    public Vote voteFor(int restaurantId, int userId) {
    ...
        Vote vote = getByRestaurantId(restaurantId);
        vote.setNumberOfVotes(vote.getNumberOfVotes() + 1)
    ...
        return vote;
    ...
    }
    ...

    }




@Entity
@Table(name = "votes", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"restaurant_id", "date", "votes"}, name = "votes_unique_restaurant_date_votes_idx")})
public class Vote extends AbstractEntity {
    @Column(name = "votes")
    private int numberOfVotes;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    public int getNumberOfVotes() {
        return numberOfVotes;
    }

    public void setNumberOfVotes(int numberOfVotes) {
        this.numberOfVotes = numberOfVotes;
    }

    public Vote() {
    }

    public Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        return restaurant;
    }

    public void setRestaurant(Restaurant restaurant) {
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vote{" +
                super.toString() +
                "numberOfVotes=" + numberOfVotes +
                ", restaurant=" + restaurant +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `VotingService` is an interface.
- The implementing class
  `VotingServiceImpl`is singleton class by default in spring. It is
  shared between threads.
- It should not have instance variable for
  holding voting information.

You can verify the correctness of the service by executing parallel request using postman or jmeter

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried jmeter. Tested for 23 users together. Works as it should. Although it is recommended to use the transaction in the implementation.